# Django Whitenoise not serving static files sometimes in ECS with debug False

Tags: python, django, collectstatic, whitenoise

My static files are not being served nicely in production with Whitenoise and Debug=False .

Sometimes it serves, sometimes it doesn't find the static.
I have the following settings:

```
# Static / Media
MEDIA_URL = os.environ.get('MEDIA_URL', '/media/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.media')
STATIC_URL = os.environ.get('STATIC_URL', '/staticfiles/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.static')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ...
```

On deploying to AWS ECS, I'm collecting static normally on docker. Also if I run `python manage.py collectstatic` locally I can find the files on my STATIC_ROOT.

The problem is on production with debug False, if I access via browser sometimes it returns the static correct, sometimes it gives a 404 error.

My packages versions:

- django==3.0.3
- whitenoise==5.0.1

What it could be? Any help please.

Comment: I faced similar issues, then I switched to django storages. Now I use S3 bucket to store my static files and I get them using Cloudfront.

Comment: Thanks @uglyCoder. I'm doing everything before going to statics on S3. The nice think about using whitenoise for me seems to be the hability to configure less thinks and since i'm using only django's admin i would like to have this working. When u switched to django storages worked (before going to S3)?